# Obscure memory error with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm creating an Objective-C library to talk with some external devices through USB.
When calling a certain method, it crashes at a random place inside the method or inside some C system functions (related to malloc or pthread) with one of the following error "invalid checksum for freed object", "autorelease pool page 0x1102032 corrupted", or even an unknown selector error (whereas the selector does exist).

Using Guard Malloc feature, it stops on this line with an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
- (void)theMethod {

// some code

NSMutableData *payloads_pool = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0x800];
NSUInteger payloads_pool_length = [payloads_pool length];

void *buffer = [payloads_pool mutableBytes];

memset(buffer, 0xCC, payloads_pool_length);

for (i = 0; i < 0x800; i += 0x40) {

    unsigned int *buf = [payloads_pool mutableBytes];

    (buf+i)[0] = 0x405;      <==== STOP ON THIS LINE
    (buf+i)[1] = 0x101;
    (buf+i)[2] = 0x8402B001;
    (buf+i)[3] = 0x8402EB01;
}

// some code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `buf` is `unsigned int*`, isn’t the pointer `+` in `buf+i` adding unsigned integers instead of bytes, thus seeking too far in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Then I'd guess that the `payloads_pool` has fewer than `0x800` bytes in.

What is the value of `i` when it crashes?

Why isn't your for loop from 0 to `payloads_pool.length`?

Comment: the value of `i` is 0x280 (640) and now it loops from 0 to `payloads_pool_length` but it doesn't change anything. Also checking local variables in the debugger it shows that `payloads_pool`is `0x800` in length

Comment: Then you should take into account @zoul 's answer - you're looping to the number of bytes but treating them as `int`s - you need to loop to `length / sizeof(int)`

Comment: The value 640 seems to confirm my answer, since if the size of `unsigned int` for your target is 4 bytes, 640*4 is past 2048 (0x800), while the previous iteration ((640-64)*4) is fine.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations !

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have enough reputation :(